# TypeScript: how to model a json object

Tags: json, typescript, typescript-typings

I want to type a variable which should be an object capable of being serialized with JSON.stringify.

I found this [definition](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15225#issuecomment-294718709) but I wonder if there's some built in type, or a better way to do it:

```js
export type JSONObject = { [key: string]: JSON }
export interface JSONArray extends Array<JSON> {}
export type JsonValue = null | string | number | boolean | JSONArray | JSONObject
```

It seems to me like it should be something pretty common.

Comment: The type of JSON is `string`. If it is not a string, then it is not JSON. You should name your type differently, maybe `JsonValue`.

Comment: good point @str, fixed it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[No builtin type for this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1897), but starting from Typescript 3.7 can be simplified to just:

```
type Json = string | number | boolean | null | Json[] | { [key: string]: Json };
```

More on recursive type aliases [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#more-recursive-type-aliases).